# Is there any way to filter YouTube videos by language?

Tags: search, youtube

Videos in search results on YouTube are often in languages different than the ones I speak and so, useless to me.

Is it possible to either make them not appear to me at all (e.g. by some account settings) or to filter them out in searches?